# Terraform - cannot use Load Balancer in AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm trying to set up AWS ECS cluster with Application Load Balancer using Terraform. For some reason I'm having error:

```
Error: InvalidParameterException: The load balancer example-production-alb does not exist. "example-production-service"
```

Here are my configs responsible for load balancing:

```
resource "aws_alb" "example-production-alb" {
  name               = "example-production-alb"
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  subnets            = var.SUBNETS_IDS
  security_groups    = [aws_security_group.example-alb-securitygroup.id]

  tags = {
    Name = "example-saas-production-alb"
  }
}

resource "aws_alb_target_group" "example-production-tg" {
  name     = "example-production-tg"
  port     = 80
  protocol = "HTTP"
  target_type = "ip"
  vpc_id   = var.VPC_ID
}

resource "aws_alb_listener" "nginx-listeners" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_alb.example-production-alb.arn
  port              = "80"
  protocol = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.example-production-tg.arn
  }
}
```

I refer to my load balancer inside the service terraform definition:

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "example-production-service" {
  name            = "example-production-service"
  cluster         = aws_ecs_cluster.example-production.id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.example-production-task-definition.arn
  desired_count   = 1
  iam_role        = aws_iam_role.ecs-service-role.arn
  depends_on      = [aws_iam_policy_attachment.ecs-service-attach]

  load_balancer {
    elb_name       = aws_alb.example-production-alb.name
    container_name = aws_ecs_task_definition.example-production-task-definition.family
    container_port = 80
  }
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [task_definition]
  }
}
```

I can see in UI that Load Balancer is there.
I would really appreciate any help. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe in case of ALB you need to provide `target_group_arn` instead of `elb_name`:

```
load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.example-production-tg.arn
    container_name   = aws_ecs_task_definition.example-production-task-definition.family
    container_port   = 80
  }
```